# how do that in str_replace

Tags: php

I have a guestbook, and I want to convert site address in the following `[link]www.yahoo.com[/link]` to `<a>...`

So how is it do that str_replace?

Comment: I don't understand what it is you want to do. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: replace  [link]www.yahoo.com[/link]  to <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">click here</a>

Comment: Could you provide some more precise input and output values? Do you want to convert "[link]www.yahoo.com[/link]" to "<a href='www.yahoo.com'>www.yahoo.com</a>"?

Comment: @alkibi: instead of adding comments to clarify, it would be better to edit the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str_replace` is not powerful enough to do this. You can use `preg_replace`:

```
$res = preg_replace('#\\[link\\](?![^:]+script:)([^:<"\\[]+:)?([^<"\\[]+)\\[/link\\]#e',
                    "'<a href=\"'.('\\1'?'\\1':'http://').'\\2\">click here</a>'",
                    $input);
```

Example: http://www.ideone.com/lTknX

But it's better to use a [BBCode parser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bbcode-create.php).

Comment: +1 to the idea of using a BBCode parser. If you try to implement this yourself you will run into edge cases that won't work until you implement a full state machine-based parser.

Comment: The linked BBCode parser is a *PECL extension*, and is not built-in to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This should do that for you:

```
$string = "[link]www.yahoo.com[/link]";

echo preg_replace("/\[link\](.*)\[\/link\]/", "<a href='$1'>click here</a>", $string);
```